# Inertia Link (Vue3) Don't work properly with web workers

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs, laravel-10

#### Version:

- `@inertiajs/vue3` version: 1.0.0
- - `Node` version: 18.16.0
- - `Vite` version: 4.0.0
- - `Laravel` version: 10.10
- - `PHP` version: 8.1

#### Description of problem:

If I use use `fetch` or `axios` inside  [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Inertia Link wait for web worker task completion. (Route shows loading until web workers complete fetching)

But for CPU intensive task like long calculation Inertia Link works perfectly (Route to another page without delay).

#### Steps to reproduce:

`Home.Vue`

```js
<template>

<Link href="/settings">Go to Settings </Link>

</template>
<script setup>
import GmailWorker from '../workers/gmailworker.js?worker'
import {Link} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import {onMounted} from "vue";

const gmailWorker = new GmailWorker()

async function getMailsFromWorker(){
    gmailWorker.postMessage('start')
    gmailWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
        if(e.data.status === "working"){
            console.log("Working....")
        }

        if(e.data.status === "done"){
            console.log("Worker done it's task: ", e.data.info)
        }

        console.log("Worker start command send")

        return true
    }
}

onMounted(() => {
 getMailsFromWorker()
})

</script>
```

`gmailworker.js`

```js
self.onmessage = function async (message) {

    postMessage({status: "working"})
    fetch("/dashboard/api/get?email=tmailaddress%2Brge1og6%40gmail.com")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            postMessage({status: 'done', info: json})
        });
}
```

*Now If I click on `Go to Settings` Link it shows loading until worker send complete response. After that Route to Setting Page. But It shouldn't wait for Worker task.*

Now if I do a CPU intensive task in gmailworkers.js

```js
 postMessage({status: "working"})
   let sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i < 10000000000; i++){
    sum += i;
    }
 postMessage({status: 'done', info: sum})
```

*In this case worker task 5-7 seconds but In any time I Click `Go to Settings` Link It's route to Setting page without waiting for works to be completed*

**Can anyone give solution about how to use `fetch/axios` inside worker in Inertia Vue3?**